# Clicked on "... may find ... disturbing or offensive" in Modern Warfare 3... is there a way to ENABLE it?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Whole title: "Some players may find some game content in one of the missions disturbing or offensive"

So ... **I clicked on the wrong option. Is there a way to revert it** and choose the "No I won't be offended by it" option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the message : "Some players may find some game content in one of the missions disturbing or offensive"

I don't believe you can change your decision on the same play through of the game. I know from personal experience that if you start another play through you will get asked again. Since it only effects one non-interactive cutscene, you may also consider just [watching it on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seFUIRGGHC4).

Comment: Oh, that's it? Thank you. Well, I don't really care about that scene.

Comment: @Shiki, in MW2, this would skip the mission "No Russian" - they always ask about the "shock value" sequence that is generally non-interactive.